# Error: "Could not open input file" when running .bat file

Tags: php, batch-file, ubuntu

I have a script in a file .bat that I need to run in Ubuntu's terminal. I run it ($./execute.bat) and I get the following error in a line:

"Could not open input file: prepare.php"

In the line inside the file, there is the command:

php prepare.php

The file prepare.php is in the same directory of execute.bat and has all permissions (chmod 777)

Why I get this error and how can I solve it?

Comment: Please post some code, the .bat for example.

Comment: see carefully permitions

Comment: .bat is a windows-ism. is that execute.bat a properly constructed shell script, with a shebang and all?

Comment: Thanks. I added, at the first line: #!/bin/sh. Then, I converted the file into a .sh and worked.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because the bat file cannot open `prepare.php` due to permissions.

Set the right permissions on `prepare.php` and it should be fine.

Comment: I set all permissions for prepare.php (chmod 777) and still get the same error.